# Agrupar consultas SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Tenho essas consultas abaixo, independentes, e estou com dificuldade de agrupa-las um mesmo resultado de consulta, ou seja, deixar as 6 colunas requisitadas pelos `select` em uma mesma consulta.

```
SELECT codigo_processo
      ,nome_produto_processo
      ,aprovado_uso
  FROM pqin
 WHERE codigo_processo = 22;

SELECT caminho_arquivo AS boletim tecnico
  FROM pqaq
 WHERE tipo_arquivo = 'BT'
   AND codigo_processo = 22;

SELECT caminho_arquivo AS fispq
  FROM pqaq
 WHERE tipo_arquivo = 'MS'
   AND codigo_processo = 22;

SELECT caminho_arquivo AS ficha de compensacao
  FROM pqaq
 WHERE tipo_arquivo = 'FC'
   AND codigo_processo = 22;
```

**Observação:** `codigo_processo` de `pqin` corresponde com `codigo_processo` de `pqaq`

Comment: A resposta lhe foi útil? Não esqueça de marcar o ✅ para que possa ser utilizada caso alguém tenha uma dúvida similar!

Answer (score 3):

Basicamente você só precisa fazer `LEFT JOIN` com ela mesma:

```
SELECT base.codigo_processo,
       base.nome_produto_processo,
       base.aprovado_uso,
       boletim.caminho_arquivo AS 'Boletim Tecnico',
       fispq.caminho_arquivo AS fispq
       ficha.caminho_arquivo AS 'Ficha de Compensacao'
FROM pqin base
     LEFT JOIN pqaq boletim ON boletim.codigo_processo = base.codigo_processo
     LEFT JOIN pqaq fispq ON fispq.codigo_processo = base.codigo_processo
     LEFT JOIN pqaq ficha ON ficha.codigo_processo = base.codigo_processo
WHERE pqin.codigo_processo = 22
  AND boletim.tipo_arquivo = 'BT'
  AND fispq.tipo_arquivo = 'MS'
  AND ficha.tipo_arquivo = 'FC'
```